# Error warning in settings for visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I've created a basic html page using visual studio code and when I've tried to do certain things like format the document using the prettier extension I get a error message to edit the settings. It started when I added the following text into the settings "liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser": "chrome"
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfZvr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ylp4A.png)

I've tried removing this and adding it back but i still get error messages when I try different commands.

If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong that would be great. At the moment my document works and is displayed as I'd expect in my browser but I can't format the document or proceed any further as I keep getting this error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to close curly braces at the end of your json file)